How to set badge count for Android notification using FMC + kreait/firebase-php?
I'm trying to add a badge count to push notifications to Android that I'm sending using Firebase Cloud Messaging and kreait/firebase-php.
My app is an appointment app and I want each notification to show the number of upcoming appointments in the badge.
With iOS, I can set the badge count using
  $message->withApnsConfig(ApnsConfig::new()->withBadge($badge_count));

How do I do the same thing for Android?
The Android API docs mention setNumber(), but I can't find where to call this in firebase-php.
EDIT: I can add to the badge count like this:
$message = $message->withAndroidConfig(AndroidConfig::fromArray([
  'notification' => [
    'notification_count' => $badge_count,
  ],
]));

However, this code adds $badge_count to the count already shown on the device, but what I want to do is set the count shown on the device to $badge_count (removing whatever the previous count was).
